# Joining 3 SQL tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables that look like this:

```
Table1:
PersonSSN
NumberOfCars

Table2:
PersonSSN
NumberOfPhones

Table3:
PersonName
PersonSSN
```

Both Table 1 and Table2 have a foreign key reference to Table3 on PersonSSN.

I need to join these in such a way that I get:
PersonName NumberOfPhones NumberOfCars

Here are some conditions that apply to the join:

1. If a person has an entry in both Table1 and Table2 I see all 3 fields populated for him.
2. If a person has an entry in Table1 and not in Table2 he should still show up but with NumberOfPhones set to 0.
3. Likewise, if a person has an entry in Table2 and not in Table1 he should still show up but with NumberOfCars set to 0.

Can this be achieved in one query ? If yes what should the query be ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a `left outer join` query:

```
select t3.name, coalesce(t1.NumberOfPhones, 0), coalesce(t2.NumberOfCars, 0)
from table3 t3 left outer join
     table1 t1
     on t3.ssn = t1.ssn left outer join
     table2 t2
     on t3.ssn = t2.ssn;
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I'm missing out data for people who are present in Table2 but not in Table1. Everything else looks good.

Comment: @Shan: Please consider providing a [SQL Fiddle test case](http://sqlfiddle.com/) demonstrating how this solution doesn't work, because, as far as I can tell, it *should* work.

Comment: @Shan . . . Are all the `SSN`s in `table3`?  This would happen if `table3` doesn't cover the whole population in the two tables.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, Yes they are.

Comment: @AndriyM, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aab00/3. Here's an example. You can see that there are records(Name2, Name3) that satisfy the WHERE clause but do not show up. Also the record for Name1 that shows up isn't accurate.

Comment: @Shan . . . The example in the SQL Fiddle is not really related to the question that you asked.  If you want help with that query, then ask another question (and include a link to the SQL Fiddle!).